# Read integers values from a file in c

Tags: c

I want to read a simple data file, where the columns are separeted by a TAB.

```
P   C   D
4   1   4
5   2   5
20  4   20
...
```

I'm trying to do like this:

```
FILE *file_ptr = fopen(system_file, "r");
if (file_ptr == NULL) {
    printf("no such file.\n");
    return 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < N_LINES; i++){
    fscanf(file_ptr, "%d %d %d ", &system.tasks[i].p, &system.tasks[i].c, &system.tasks[i].d);
}
```

But when i print the values from `system.tasks` it always returns `0` for all.

Comment: Always check the return value of any input function.

Comment: what is `system.tasks`?

Comment: Aside: see [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string) The format strign should be `"%d %d %d"` or `"%d%d%d"` but no final (white)space.

Comment: The `fscanf` loop will get stuck at the non-integer values on the first line. Always check the return value, which here must be `3`. I suggest you read each line with `fgets()` and apply `sscanf()`.

Comment: `while(i < N_LINES && fgets(buff, sizeof buff, file_ptr ) != NULL) {
    if(sscanf(buff, "%d%d%d", &system.tasks[i].p, &system.tasks[i].c, &system.tasks[i].d) == 3) i++; }`

Comment: @Z4-tier It is like as in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot tell what is happening because you do not test the return value of `fscanf()` so you do not know where the parsing fails.

You properly test for `fopen` failure, but you should provide a meaningful error message.

Furthermore, parsing a file with `fscanf()` is error prone because white space skipped when parsing numbers and strings may include line breaks.

It is much more reliable to read the file one line at a time with `fgets()` and parse the line with `sscanf()` (or other more precise functions such as `strtol`). Testing the return value of `sscanf()` is **very** important to detect invalid contents and prevent subsequent undefined behavior as the destination variables will not have been updated.

Here is a modified version using `fgets()` to read one line at a time:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct task {
    int p, c, d;
    //...
};

#define N_LINES 100
struct system {
    struct task tasks[N_LINES];
    //...
} system;

int main() {
    char buf[256];
    const char *system_file = "system.txt";
    FILE *file_ptr = fopen(system_file, "r");
    if (file_ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", system_file, strerror(errno));

    int line = 0;
    // skip the header line
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file_ptr);
    line++;
    // parse the file contents
    for (int i = 0; i < N_LINES;) {
        line++;
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file_ptr)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: missing records\n",
                    system_file, line);
            break;
        }
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d%d%d", &system.tasks[i].p,
                   &system.tasks[i].c, &system.tasks[i].d) == 3) {
            i++;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: invalid format: %s", 
                    system_file, line, buf);
        } 
    }
    fclose(file_ptr);
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you for 1) mentioning the importance of checking the return value from "*scanf()", 2) Suggesting "fgets()" as an alternative, 3) suggesting "strerror()" to give a meaningful "file open error" diagnostic message.

Comment: Nitpick: Note that ISO C does not require `fopen` to set `errno` on failure. Therefore, it is theoretically possible that `"cannot open input.txt: No error"` will be printed. However, I am unaware of any platform which does not set `errno` (POSIX requires this). In order to make the program also work on platforms that do not set `errno`, the program could set `errno` to `0` before calling `fopen` and then test whether `errno` is still `0` when `fopen` returns `NULL`. If that is the case, then a general error message could be printed instead of calling `perror` or `strerror`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: good point: the C Standard does not mandate setting `errno` on stream operation failures and indeed only defines very few error values for `errno`. The POSIX standard is much more consistent and any system that would not set `errno` on such failures would show poor quality of implementation.